# how do you visualise automatic input field value change

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a form with several rows of similar data. To improve user experience I would like to automate filling out of the form, for instance it makes sense to fill down one column with the value entered in the first row. But I would also like to visualise automatic filling out of data.

I plan to use jQuery UI on this form.

Question is what do you suggest as a way of visualisation of automatic filling out? What have you used in similar situation in your projects? Perhaps you can propose other UI library from jQuery-UI?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to keep the automatically changed input highlighted or just want to have it highlighted for some seconds when the corresponding input was changed, but as example using jQuery UI - first setting the background color of the corresponding input and then fading back to white:

```
<input type="text" id="one-1" class="one" />
<input type="text" id="two-1" class="two" />
<input type="text" id="one-2" class="one" />
<input type="text" id="two-2" class="two" />

$("input").change(function () {
  $("input." + $(this).attr("class")).val($(this).val());
  $("input." + $(this).attr("class")).not(this)
   .css("background-color", "lime")
   .animate({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hu7v3tj/) (I've tried to add as stack snippet but it wasn't working with the external jQuery UI).